# How can I find last child in array list like tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, tree

Hi I have dynamic tree data like below containing children, may increase the like tree8,tree9 node and children how can I find the name of the node that had the last child and all id's, As I said, this tree structure can continue dynamically. answer for the example below last child node name tree4, and all tree is = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
The important point here is that I cannot find how to do it when dynamic data arrives, thanks for suggestion

```
  let tree = {
    id: 1,
    name: "tree1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "tree2",
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "tree4",
            children: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: "tree6"
              },
              {
                id: 7,
                name: "tree7"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "tree5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "tree3"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Comment: What's the expected output if tree6 and tree7 have children?

Comment: it could only be someone's child for example tree7 have children I expected output is tree7 and all id names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function

```
// Based on your question and solution , I can see that you want to check only children[0] object for children.

let noChildParent;
let id = [];

let checkIfChildrenExist = (prop,parentName) =>{
  //console.log(prop,noChildrenParent);
  if(prop.children == null)
  {                         
    noChildParent = parentName;  
    return
  }  
    checkIfChildrenExist(prop.children[0],prop.name); \\ recursive pattern
}


let checkId = (prop)=>{
  //console.log(prop.id);
  id.push(prop.id);
  if(prop.children == null) return;   
    prop.children.forEach((el)=>{
      checkId(el); 
    });
    }

checkIfChildrenExist(tree);
checkId(tree);

console.log("noChildParent",noChildParent, "ID",id); // tree4 // [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 5, 3]
//You can sort  id array if you want it to be in specific order
```